# Slow Boot: "A start job is running for /boot"

Tags: linux, boot, centos, esxi

I'm running a CentOS 7.2 VM on ESXi 6.0, using thick provisioning, no CPU hot add and one virtual SCSI drive/controller.  It runs fine, except that booting seems abnormally slow.  I checked the boot process and it seems to take a long time to mount the drive partitions:

```
[  ***  ] A start job is running for /boot (1min 15s 2m 0s)
```

Why is this job taking so long?

Comment: Is `/boot` mounted after it booted up though (i.e. did the job fail after all)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Centos 7 that causes booting to hang for a long time if the /boot partition is xfs (which is unfortunately the default fs type). If your /boot fs is xfs this is the reason. Use ext4. I don't know of a workaround.

Comment: Do you have a link to this bug?